Substituting propositional variables given a true biconditional
Say I know that $p ↔ q$ AND $q ↔ (p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q)$ are both true. From hypothetical syllogism, the logical equivalence $(x → y) ∧ (x → z) ≡ x → (y ∧ z),$ and the simplification $(x ∧ y→ y$ is a tautology) we'd see that:
(1) $(p ↔ q) ∧ (q ↔ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))) ≡ (p→ q) ∧ (q→ p) ∧ (q→ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))) ∧ (((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))→ q) $
(2) $p→ q ∧ (q→ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q)))$ // Simplification of (1)
(3) $p→ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))$ // Hypothetical syllogism of (2)
(4) $(((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))→ q) ∧ q→ p$ // Simplification of (1)
(5) $((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))→ p$ // Hypothetical syllogism of (4)
(6) $p ↔ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))$ // Conjunction of (3) and (5)
Since I know that $p ↔ q$ from givens, could I just replace $q$ with $p$ in (6) to get $p ↔ ((p ∧ ¬p) ∨ (¬p ∧ p))),$ hence $p ↔ F$ and $p$ is false. Furthermore since $p ↔ q$ is true, $q$ must also be false. Is this a correct substitution to do?

See Rule of replacement and this post about replacement and Substitution in deduction.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry the stuff seems more in-depth then what I've learned in school/textbook. Is my substitution correct though?

Am I missing something?  If you are gonna replace $q$ with $p$, why not instead replace $p$ with $q$ in the original, and immediately get $q ↔ F$?

@antkam Ya true! I guess I could've done the substitution right in the beginning to get the truth values of p & q. I guess I didn't realize that when writing the question since I just copied down all my work from the problem I was trying to solve and was thinking many things at once. But even though steps (1) to (6) don't directly relate to the question, the main question still holds regarding this substitution technique I employed, which I don't see mentioned in textbooks despite it being rather intuitive.

tbh, i dont know enough about formal logic to know that you are allowed do a substitution like that.  i was simply saying, if you are allowed, then there is an easier way.  (in fact, i would imagine this is not allowed, formally.)


Say I know that $$p ↔ q$$ AND $$q ↔ (p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q)$$ are both true. we'd see that:
(1) $$(p ↔ q) ∧ (q ↔ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q)))\\ ≡ (p→ q) ∧ (q→ p) ∧ (q→ ((p
∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))) ∧ (((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))→ q) $$
(2) $\quad p→ q ∧ (q→ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q)))$ // Simplification of (1)
(3) $\quad p→ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))$ // Hypothetical syllogism of (2)
(4) $\quad (((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))→ q) ∧ q→ p$ // Simplification of (1)
(5) $\quad ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))→ p$ // Hypothetical syllogism of (4)
(6) $\quad p ↔ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))$ // Conjunction of (3) and (5)

$(p ↔ q) \quad∧\quad (q ↔ ((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q)))\tag{1a}$
$ (p→ q) ∧ (q→ p) ∧ (q→ ((p∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))) ∧ (((p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬p ∧ q))→ q) \tag{1b}$
(1a) implies (1b), which implies (2), which implies (3).
(1a) implies (1b), which implies (4), which implies (5).
Hence, (1a) implies the conjunction of (3) and (5), and this conjunction implies (6).

Since I know that $p ↔ q$ from givens, could I just replace $q$ with
$p$ in (6) to get $p ↔ ((p ∧ ¬p) ∨ (¬p ∧ p))),$ hence $p ↔ F$ and $p$
is false. Furthermore since $p ↔ q$ is true, $q$ must also be false.
Is this a correct substitution to do?

Yes, so (1a) logically implies that $p$ and $q$ are both contradictions. (The converse is straightforward to prove.)
